# Why is "decrementation" not a word?

Tags: word-usage

In OneNote, I don't get spell check errors for "incrementation", but do for "decrementation".

[image]

Weird. So are they actual words or not?

Comment: See [this Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decrementation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecrementation%3B%2Cc0) for published occurrences of _decrementation_ for the period 1800–2008. Evidently, the most relevant question isn't "Is _decrementation_ a word"? (it is a word) but "Why doesn't Microsoft Word recognize _decrementation_ as a word?"—and the answer to that question is almost surely "Because it is a relatively rare word and/or a word that began to appear with significant frequency only in the past few decades."

Comment: @SvenYargs  I thought spell checks were based off of dictionaries and not popularity contest.

Comment: @NoName Spell checks are based on dictionaries as far as I know, but the matter of whether something is a word (which was the OP's question) is indeed a popularity contest, even among the most trusted dictionaries (or, I should say, in considering whether a word is included in a dictionary).

Answer (score -3):

"Incrementation" and "decrementation" are little used words, probably because the words are useless.
You can say
"the exit condition will be reached by increment or decrement"
or you can say
"the exit condition will be reached by incrementing or decrementing"
There is no need to say
"the exit condition will be reached by incrementate or decrementate"
There is no need to say
"the exit condition will be reached by incrementating or decrementating"
There is no need to say
"the exit condition will be reached by incrementation or decrementation"

Comment: With this criterion for "useless", half of all words are useless, and we might as well just start using Orwell's Newspeak.